# Are there any rules for mixing capital and small letters in acronyms?

Tags: acronyms

In documentation for electrical vehicles there is a common acronym for "state of charge" that is written as "SoC" or "SOC".

Are both versions equally ok, or are there rules guiding when to mix case, and when not to mix case?

I hope this question doesn't fall under the category "Questions that are primarily opinion-based", which I learned are not be asked here (I just signed up).

Comment: Given that the acronym won't have much meaning outside of the EV domain, I'd suggest looking at the existing documentation and using the most common version...of course, that's just my opinion.

Comment: Why don't you do the research instead of us? It generally depends on what the authors want. There is no rule.

Comment: Of course I tried to find an answer before asking here. Maybe my skills using Google and ChatGPT could be better, of course. That I did not find a rule did not prove to me there was none, hence the post here.

Comment: Here’s the part where someone tosses in the observation that many authorities advise against calling *SoC* or *SOC* an acronym if it’s not pronounced like *sock*, the name of the article of clothing. If instead they are pronounced “ess oh see,” then those authorities would call it an initialism. *NASA*? Acronym. *FBI*? Initialism.

Comment: Of course it could also be SC, as words like "of" aren't always included in abbreviations (e.g. USA). These things seem to be governed by fashion, but assuming this is fairly recent as an EV term, I'm not sure what is currently in style.

Comment: SOC is going to be read as Special Operations Command by an awful lot of folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules of when lowercase is acceptable are fairly loose, the most important thing is to *be consistent* with existing literature, or if there is none, be consistent with whatever form you pick. Oftentimes you'll see acronyms  use all capital letters, but it is also acceptable to represent shorter or less important words as lowercase letters, mimicking the capitalization that would be used in title case. You'll rarely be wrong using all-caps, but watch out for existing acronyms that use lowercase.

I'm not familiar with the acronym you mention, but a similar one, "standard of care", can be abbreviated as either SoC or SOC depending on the style of the author. It seems either would be acceptable in your case as well.